# My Application crashes immediately on android Emulator after click on login button in react native.However works perfectly fine on iOS Simulator

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My Multivendor Food Ordering Application crashes immediately on android Emulator when clicked on login button in react native . However works  perfectly fine on iOS Simulator. I am not able to login when i press the login it immediately exits my app to the emulator normal screen. However i have lot of functionalities on Login until a user cannot login he/she is not able to do anything like he/she not able to place an order or pay for the same order. However neither i am getting any error nor any warning on the terminal. Also the Application is not working in Debug mode when I try to launch in Debug mode it gets crashed or killed. Rest Of the Functionality works fine like adding an item item, navigating the restaurant products, search the restaurant, deleting an item in cart etc  Below is the Code for Login

```
`import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

import FormContainer from "../../Shared/Form/FormContainer";

import Input from "../../Shared/Form/Input";

import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";

import AuthGlobal from "../../Context/store/AuthGlobal";

import { loginUser } from "../../Context/actions/Auth.actions";

const Login = (props) => {

  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {

    if (context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === true) {

      props.navigation.navigate("User Detail");

    }

  }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated]);


  const handleSubmit = () => {

    const user = {

      email,
      password,

    };

    if (email === "") {

      Toast.show({

        type: "error",
        text1: `Email Is required`,
        text2: "Please try again",

      });
    } else if (password === "") {

      Toast.show({
        type: "error",
        text1: `Password is Required`,
        text2: "Please try again",
      });
    } else {
      loginUser(user, context.dispatch);
    }
  };

  return (

    <FormContainer title={"Login"}>
      <Input
        placeholder={"Enter Email"}
        name={"email"}
        id={"email"}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text.toLowerCase())}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder={"Enter Password"}
        name={"password"}
        id={"password"}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
        <Button title="Login" onPress={() => handleSubmit()}></Button>
      </View>
      <View style={[{ marginTop: 40 }, styles.buttonGroup]}>
        <Text style={styles.middleText}>Don't have an account yet?</Text>
        <Button
          title="Sign up"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
        >
          {/* <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Register</Text> */}
        </Button>
      </View>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  buttonGroup: {
    width: "80%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  middleText: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});

export default Login;`

This is the loginUser which i have imported in Login Component

  `export const loginUser = (user, dispatch) => {

  const { email, password } = user;

  axios({

    method: "POST",

    url: `${baseURL}signin`,

    data: { email: email.toLowerCase(), password: password },
   
  })
    .then((response) => {
     
      if (response) {
        
        const token = response.data.token;

        AsyncStorage.setItem("jwt", token);

        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded, user));

      } else {

        logoutUser(dispatch);

      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {

      console.log("SIGNIN ERROR", error.response.data.error);

      Toast.show({
        topOffset: 60,
        type: "error",
        text1: `${error.response.data.error}`,
        text2: "Please Try again!  test",
      });
    });
};`
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: I added the code For Whole Login Component and the loginUser function which i have imported in Login Component

Comment: What have you tried so far ?
It's kinda hard to reproduce it like that.
And please indent the code properly, so that others show interest in helping you.

Comment: It's by default but recheck in manifest file that internet permission.